# Is this React countdown function valid?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I want to write a function for a Pomodoro clock, as here https://codepen.io/freeCodeCamp/full/XpKrrW

Will the function given be able to countdown?  My entire code so far : https://codepen.io/corpsist/pen/bGEGboZ

```
handleClick(){
  this.setState({
    running : !(this.state.running)
  })
  var myInterval = () => {
    setInterval(function(){
    if(this.state.seconds>0){
      this.setState({
        timerTile : 'Session',
        seconds : this.state.seconds - 1
      })
    }
    else if(this.state.seconds === 0){
      if(this.state.minutes === 0){
          this.setState({
            timerTitle : 'Break', 
            minutes : this.state.breakMinutes
          })
          myInterval();

      }
      else{
        this.setState({
          minutes : this.state.minutes-1,
          seconds : 59
        })
       }
      }
    },1000);
  }
};
```

Comment: You're not going to get an exact 1-second cycle on each pass through `setInterval`. It's better to calculate the actual time on each pass: `let currtime = new Date().getTime()`

Comment: Try posting this @[codereview (stackexchange)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript)